# jQuery click() on class "flag en"

Tags: jquery, click

How can I detect if I'm clicking on the class "flag en"

I usually do $('.class').click(function(){ command }); but this class is "flag en", and if I try with $('.flag en') it is not working;

Comment: "flag en" is not a class.  It is two classes; "flag" and "en"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flag en` is two seperate classes.  Try changing your selector to this:

```
$('.flag.en').click(function(){ command });
```

`$('.flag en')` would match an `en` element (no such thing) that is a descendant of an element with the `flag` class.  By changing it to `.flag.en` you are specifying an element that has both the `flag` and the `en` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
$('.flag.en').click(function(){ command });
```